# Let TextView inside custom component inherit all attributes

Tags: java, android, inheritance, attributes, custom-component

I'm creating a custom component called `IconButton`<sup>1</sup>, that extends `ConstraintLayout`:

```java
package com.example.widget;

public class IconButton
    extends androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout {

    /* implementation */
}
```

... and whose layout will look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"/>

</merge>
```

If I now define styleable attributes for my component like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="IconButton">
        <attr name="android:text"/>
        <attr name="android:textSize"/>
        <attr name="android:fontFamily"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

... and then use my component like this:

```xml
<com.example.widget.IconButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Press me!"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
    />
```

... is there a way to have the `TextView` inside my button layout automatically inherit all attributes that are applicable to it (the last three in the above case), **without** having to do it programmatically like the following?

```java
public IconButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray customAttrs = context.getTheme()
        .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IconButton, 0, 0);

    /* programmatically apply all applicable attributes to TextView */
}
```

---

<sup>1) I know that `android.widget.Button` can have drawables, but I want to use vector images and I haven't found a way to scale those vector images inside `android.widget.Button`</sup>

Comment: you can use TextView. it has property drawableEndCompat. like this

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_pro" />

Comment: @Raza Thanks! I didn't realize that those attributes existed on `TextView`. However, it still won't allow me to scale the vector image. My `IconButton` will have an attribute `iconSize` to set the size of the icon.